# Sailpoint Identity IQ generates an error: sailpoint.connector.ConnectorException: Build Rule must return a Map

Tags: sailpoint

I want to display only the identities whose type is either "interne" or "externe".
Here is my code in Sailpoint:

```
import sailpoint.connector.DelimitedFileConnector;
Map map = DelimitedFileConnector.defaultBuildMap(cols, record);
String Type = (String) map.get( "TYPE" );
  
if(!Type.contains("Interne") && !Type.contains("Externe")){
          return null;
 }
return map;
```

When i launch an aggregation account task, i have the error:
Exception lors du regroupement. Cause : java.lang.RuntimeException: sailpoint.connector.ConnectorException: Build Rule must return a Map.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are directly calling the `DelimitedFileConnector.defaultBuildMap(cols, record);` which may return, so inturn you are not returning a empty hashmap, but a null value.

So i would change the following.

```
return null!=map ? map:new HashMap();
```

This way you are checking for map is null or not and return correct value.

Answer (score 0):

The rule should just be:

```
import sailpoint.connector.DelimitedFileConnector;
Map map = DelimitedFileConnector.defaultBuildMap(cols, record);
String Type = (String) map.get( "TYPE" );
  
if(!Type.contains("Interne") && !Type.contains("Externe")){
          return new HashMap();
 }
return map;
```